# Use Logging SocketHandler with Django

Tags: django, logging

I've configured my logging as so:

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'cute':{
            'class': 'logging.handlers.SocketHandler',
            'host': '127.0.0.1',
            'port': 19996
        },
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['cute'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
        },
    },
}
```

But when I try and log out I get an error in the console:

```
TypeError: an integer is required (got type socket)
```

This seems to be happening within an attempt to pickle the log message, I think.

What is going on, and how can I get the `SocketHandler` to work?

Comment: What line gives you this error?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29186) about it. The request object cannot be pickled and the log fails.

My loggers were like yours before I got the same error as you did. Since my code contains apps that don't work with request, I partially fixed my problem creating a log for `django.request` without `socket_handler`

```
'django.request': {
        'handlers': ['defaultfile', 'console'],
        'level': 'WARNING',
        'propagate': False,
    },
```

However the [bug report](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/29186) also suggest to create a custom SocketHandler removing request:

```
from logging.handlers import SocketHandler as _SocketHandler

class DjangoSocketHandler(_SocketHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        if hasattr(record, 'request'):
            record.request = None
        return super().emit(record)
```

I haven't tried this yet, but it could be a way to go.